# Как правильно установить стабильный FPS в игре?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sfml

Имеется:

- Среднее время между итерациями цикла, рисующего кадр в секундах, миллисекундах и микросекундах, на выбор (double deltaTime).
- Скорость перемещения объекта (double Speed = 2)

Как правильно привязать к этому времени, что бы получить стабильный FPS в нужное кол-во кадров?? (30 / 60 / 100 и т.д.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот общий код, главное получить счётчик времени, чтобы высчитать разницу.

```
int framelimit = 90; //ограничим FPS до 90
int now = 0;
unsigned sceneStartTime = 0;
unsigned sceneSkipTime = 1000 / framelimit;
while(true){
     //ищем разницу во времени
     now = getTime();
     if (now - sceneStartTime > sceneSkipTime){
                sceneStartTime = getTime();
                //код игры здесь
     }
}
```

Код выше делался под irrlicht, у меня лично возникали проблемы с таким способом, пришлось написать по своему. Тут уже всё нормально. Но максимум ограничения до 120.

```
float num_fps_limit = 60.f;
float fps_limit_timer = 0.f;
float fps_lim = 1/num_fps_limit;

float frameDeltaTime;
int now = 0, then = 0;
while( true ){
   now = getTime();
   frameDeltaTime = (float)(now - then)/1000.f;
   fps_limit_timer += frameDeltaTime;

   if (fps_limit_timer >= fps_lim ){
      fps_limit_timer = 0.0f;

      //тут остальной код
   }

   then = now;

}
```

Comment: Зачем так нагружать процессор (пустым циклом)? Сделайте хотя бы sleep или WaitForSingleObject... Синхронизируйтесь с обьектом таймер. Без IDLE вы рискуете нагрузить процессор на 100% (что не обязательно), владельцы ноутов будут недовольны разогревом ПК.

Answer (score 0):

```
sf::Window window(sf::Videomode(200, 200), "wind");
window.setFramerateLimit(60); //вместо 60 указать fps
```